# There is no smooth diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb R^3 \setminus [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^3 \to \mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I want to prove thtat there is no smooth diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb R^3 \setminus [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^3 \to \mathbb R^3$.
Attempt:
I have seen a lot about $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$, I don't know if here it works the same way, since the hole is of similar type, but not just one point. 
We know that the second de Rham cohomology group of $\mathbb R^3$ vanishes: $$H^2(\mathbb R^3) = \{0\}.$$
However, take the $2$-form $\omega $ defined by $$\omega_{(x,y,z)} := \frac{x\, dy \wedge dz + y \,dz\wedge dx + z \,dx\wedge dy}{(x^2+y^2+z^3)^{3/2}}$$
It is a quick calculation that $\omega$ is closed, i.e. $\omega \in Z^2(\mathbb R^3\setminus[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^3). $ But since $$\int_{S^2} \omega = 4\pi \neq 0,$$
$\omega$ is not exact ($[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^3 \subseteq B_1(0)$). Now if there was a smooth diffeomorphism $f$, $\omega$ pullbacked with $f^{-1}$ would be a non-exact form too since the cohomology classes are the same. Is this correct?

Comment: As far as I remember homotopically equivalent spaces have the same cohomology, so the De Rham cohomology classes of the space you're considering should be the same as $\Bbb R^3\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: Oh, that could indeed be true. But is the reasoning that no smooth diffeomorphism can exist correct?

Comment: Indeed, any potential diffeomorphism $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3 \setminus [-1/2,1/2]^3$ gives rise to an isomorphism of their respective DeRham cohomology groups. Since $H^2(\mathbb R^3) = 0$, this would also imply that $H^2( \mathbb R^3 \setminus [-1/2,1/2]^3) = 0$, contradicting the fact that $[\omega] \neq 0$, as you have proven.

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate my comment into an answer since it's getting longer.

Yes, you're right. The space you're considering, let's call it $A$, is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{ 0\}$, hence no homeomorphism exists between $A$ and $\Bbb R^3$. This also implies that there is no diffeomorphism between these two spaces.

Exhibiting a 2-form like you did is also right, though what I was saying is that being the two spaces homotopically equivalent, their De Rham groups are going to be isomorphic.

Comment: I think your answer is missing the word "not" in several vital places: "not homeomorphic to", "not homotopy equivalent" and "not going to be isomorphic" (but then the implication in the last paragraph is false).

Comment: thank you so much man, I actually forgot to 'delete' the zero point in all those places

Comment: How do you show, without asserting to homology/cohomology, that $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb R^3$ are not homeomorphic ?

Comment: @RobArthan yeah, that's what I wrote, I don't see any problem now though

Comment: The simplest way I know of showing that $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb R^3$ are not homeomorphic **is** by calculating their respective cohomology groups. Unless you provide us with another, simpler proof of that fact, delete the line "cohomology seems like a bit an overkill for me" ;)

Comment: @BerniWaterman I just did, thank you.